# Dynamically load user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, user-controls

I have this `GridView` that have it's `DataSource` as a list of previously selected products.
For every item on it, I need to Eval it's ID and load a specifc form that the user must fill, then after that i've got to update the GridView.

I have made those specific forms as `User Controls`, is this the best approach for this scenario?

If yes, how can I dynamically load them, in a way that I can make queries/postbacks then update back my gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to develop is called Master/Detail view.
It is described for example in http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs .

The only difference that as Detail you need use FormView, where on some initialization event (like DataBound http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx )you need to dynamically create you control and set its parent to current template of FormView